# Vauxhall Astra diesel replacement clutch

Tags: oil, clutch, vauxhall

Could someone let me know if a clutch and flywheel is changed on a Vauxhall Astra diesel do they change the gearbox oil as part of the job. Many thank

Comment: I don't know specifically for the Vauxhall Astra, but for most vehicles the answer is **no**. In fact, if there isn't any contamination of the gear fluid (like water), the gear oil/fluid usually isn't changed at all. The only other time it gets changed is if they gearbox is rebuilt.

Comment: Yeah, he is right. I also never change the oil by changing clutch. It just will be filled with the old oil again and just sometimes filled to level with the bit on new one, if some oil was lost.

Comment: If by "change" you mean "put in new oil", then no. If you mean "Do they have to let the oil out and put it back", then yes. What year model is it, something after 2005?

Answer (score 1):

The Vauxhall Astra gearbox oil does not have a quoted service life. If the oil is drained in to a clean container, and the oil itself has'nt been contaminated then it will be OK to re-use. There are several transmissions on the Astra Range and several have to have their own particular spec of gearbox oil. Vauxhall also recommend changing the trans drain and filler plugs (?) on some variants.

Comment: I think the newer models all (or most) use a version of the M32 gearbox.